# ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com

Tags: node.js, git, nginx, github

hello I am getting this error when I try to pull from my remote reposotory github

```
youssef@alyAppTest:~/alyBackend$ git pull origin master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: No address associated with hostname
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have no idea why , it was working fine just minute ago .

when I run git remote -v it still point to the right repository

also checkin the file `..git/config`  below it seems it has the right values

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:{USERNAME}/{REPOS}.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

thing I did recently to the server :
i did use a lot pull and push command is there a limit to number of these command ?

also I did install nginx on my server , could that have an impact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. Github status page says they are having problems currently: https://www.githubstatus.com/

EDIT:
Status page has been updated

> Update - An update to our nameservers has been rolled back. We are monitoring recovery.
> Jun 22, 20:00 UTC

Comment: Thank you Emil !

Comment: Direct link to the incident: https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/shdhxntw519h